# Why isn't the python function updating arguments on recursive call

Tags: python, for-loop, recursion

I am learning Python.

I have a task to find the numbers in a list that sum up to the target number.

My attempt is this:

```
def two_sum(numbers, target):
    # subtraction
    numbers.sort(reverse=True)
    if (len(numbers)>=2):
        for k,v in enumerate(numbers):
            count=difference(v,target)
            print(v,list(count))
            
def difference(number,targetdiff):
    valid=1
    count=0
    while valid!=0:
        print(f"targetdiff={targetdiff}--number={number}")
        if (targetdiff >=number):
            diff=targetdiff-number
            yield difference(number,diff)
            count+=1
        else:
            valid=0
            yield count
```

The loop is infinetly stuck and somehow the recurring function isn't taking my new arguments.

Input:

```
two_sums([1, 2, 3], 4)
```

Output:

```
targetdiff=4--number=3
targetdiff=4--number=3
targetdiff=4--number=3
targetdiff=4--number=3
...
```

I've ended up confusing myself and don't understand why this behaviour is occurring, any advice?

*** Update from feedback.

The task is to find out which factors in the input list sum up to the target, assuming each factor could fit multiple times in the target number.

My way of trying to solve this was:
take a number from the input list and subtract it from the target number and then count how many times that number can be subtracted and return the count to the list.

The next part (which I haven't attempted yet) was to take the remainder (once I return it from the difference function (not yet implemented) and cycle through the remaining numbers in the input list.

Expected output (from highest factor to lowest) could be:
[3,1] if the target is 4

There could be other factors that make up 4, but I'm just seeking the approach of finding the largest factors (why I introduce the sort function). Other numbers can be valid e.g.:
[[1,1,1,1],[2,1,1],[2,2],[3,1]]
In this the largest factor would be [3,1]

Comment: Firstly, you don't want to yield a generator. If you want to chain generators, you should use `yield from difference(number, diff)`. Secondly, if you look at your loop body, you can see that neither `number` nor `diff` is updated, that means it will just infinitely loop with or without the `yield from`. You need to somehow update `targetdiff` or `number`, or just `break` from the loop. As I don't know what your function is supposed to do (you didn't give any expected output), I cannot fix the code for you.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I'm trying to find the factors that add up to the target number. The factors are in the list. My approach is to subtract them to find them. I'm still unsure what the broken logic is I'm afraid.

Comment: Explain to yourself how you expect the `difference` function to do anything useful, since it doesn't know which numbers are available in the input list. You just give it one of the numbers of the input list and the target, but it has no way to know whether there is a second number that can make up the difference. Also, why do you make a recursive call? How will that help? Usually you would *either* use recursion, *or* use a loop. Think of which of the two you want to use. Combining them seems not useful here.

Comment: Can you edit the question to add the expected output? Are you just counting or do you need the actual factors? If you are just counting, I don't see why a generator is needed and a simple recursive function call is not sufficient. Right now it seems when the count is for example 4 you are just yielding things like 0,1,2,3,4.

Comment: Please include the output you anticipate to be correct for your example input.

Comment: It is still not clear. Do you want `two_sums([1, 2, 3], 4)` to give you `[3,1]`, or what? If you want it to give you `[[1,1,1,1],[2,1,1],[2,2],[3,1]]` you need to clearly say so.

Comment: clearly it's very obvious to everyone what my fault is. I need to look more carefully into your feedback to unpick what I just can't see. My view is that I'm cycling through the input list (for loop), then doing a recursive call in difference to see how many time that number can be used until it's larger than the targetdiff, at which point I need to exit the method and cycle through the other numbers in the input list to see what would fit.

Comment: 1. Why are you using `yield`? Do you understand what this does? If not, you should read about generators. Since your question is about recursion, I highly doubt this is even what you want.

Comment: 2. Don't use a loop and recursion together. For a beginner exercise, you typically want one or ther other but not both.

Comment: To further debug this, add a `print()` in each branch of the `if...else`. This should give you some insight into what is happening in your code. Be sure to print out the values of `value` and `count` to see if they change. You should also add a `print()` at the top of the function to see each time it gets called. For more debugging tips , read [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: "take a number from the input list and subtract it from the target number and then count how many times that number can be subtracted." Isn't that just integer division? Or do you purposely use subtraction to implement this as a practice for recursion?

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. Yes I could do division but I'm trying to learn recursion

Comment: My understanding was to always use yield as then recursion would not eat all the memory

Answer (score 0):

The reason why your function stucks is because the loop ends only if `valid=0` so when `targetdiff <number`.

As a consequence you have to update the value of `targetdiff`to meet the exit condition.
Otherwise the function stucks in an infinite loop.

**Proposed modification**

```py
def difference(number,targetdiff):
    valid=1
    count=0
    while valid!=0:
        print(f"targetdiff={targetdiff}--number={number}")
        if (targetdiff >=number):
            diff=targetdiff-number
            yield difference(number,diff)
            ### targetdiff = update(...)
            count+=1
        else:
            valid=0
            yield count
```

Comment: But it is updated when I call `diff=targetdiff-number`

Comment: only diff is updated in this case, not targetdiff

Comment: As already commented in the question, `yield difference(number,diff)` is wrong. It will yield a generator as the result of your iteration, which is definitely not wanted.

Comment: I can't see what you exactly want to do. But in any case if you want to exit an infinite loop you should turn the while condition to `False` during the code execution. Otherwise, it stucks.

Comment: See the `else` condition will turn it to false on the last recursion of the difference call. As the number won't subtract fro the targetdiff. Why wouldn't it be set to `valid=0` on the lsat recursion call?

Comment: ahh you are stating it would be false, but the targetdiff logic needs to be fixed